# CSS Width Limit

Tags: html, css

How can I make h3 tag appear like this?

[image]

I tried to apply width and max-width css rules (e.g width: 120px; or 150px) but the words appears to each next to each other.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways to do that:

```
h3{
 text-transform:uppercase;
 background:green;
 color:white;   
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 width:100px;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fgu6W/

There are more than few, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h3> SELL <br> ANYWHERE </h3>
```

Comment: your html is invalid and the OP was asking how to do it with CSS, right?

Comment: What is invalid? And this can be an alternative solution if he wants to use html instead.

Comment: haha you changed it, you know exactly what was invalid.  You had `<h3 SELL <br> ANYWHERE </h3>` with no closing `>` on your opening `h3` tag

Comment: Yeah sorry I changed it before you asked. Think you did not refresh your page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more HTML/CSS code for a better answer, but with the information provided I would assume you may need to set your `h3` tag to `display: block`

In this example, I did not need to set display to `block`, it just works:  http://jsfiddle.net/vwwZs/

So maybe you have some other conflicting CSS being applied.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
<h3 style="text-align:center;">
SELL
<br>
ANYWHERE
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-align:center` combined with fixed width : http://jsfiddle.net/wQUyR/

```
h3 {
    background:blue;
    display:block;
    width:70px;
    text-align:center;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
<h3 style="width:120px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;">Sell Anywhere</h3>
```

Without inline styling:

```
<h3 class="sell-anywhere">Sell Anywhere</h3>

h3.sell-anywhere
{
   width: 120px;
   text-alignment:center;
   text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6f4Z/3/) and it would be great if you provide your code.

```
<h3 style="width:100px;text-align:center;color:white;background:black"> SELL ANYWHERE </h3>​
```